# Nextjs 13.2.1 App Dir - Error: Page changed from static to dynamic at runtime

Tags: postgresql, orm, supabase, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

## Bug Description

I get an error when fetching data from Supabase using their ORM-like syntax. It first fetches the data, then the app crashes with the following error message.

```
error - Error: Page changed from static to dynamic at runtime /en/habitaciones
see more here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/app-static-to-dynamic-error
    at doRender (C:\creative-dev\coding\web\repos\hqnrd\node_modules\.pnpm\next@13.2.1_biqbaboplfbrettd7655fr4n2y\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:818:29)
    at async cacheEntry1.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (C:\creative-dev\coding\web\repos\hqnrd\node_modules\.pnpm\next@13.2.1_biqbaboplfbrettd7655fr4n2y\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:926:28)
    at async C:\creative-dev\coding\web\repos\hqnrd\node_modules\.pnpm\next@13.2.1_biqbaboplfbrettd7655fr4n2y\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:83:36 {
  page: '/en/habitaciones'
}
```

In order to support multiple languages, I placed all pages and components files within a dynamic route app\[lang].

*My heart tells me this is in part what's triggering the error but I haven't been able to fully understand these rendering strategies yet.*

### Middleware config

```
// Dependencies
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

// i18n-config.ts contans the i18n object and the Locale type
import { i18n } from "./i18n-config";

import { match as matchLocale } from "@formatjs/intl-localematcher";
import Negotiator from "negotiator";

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
    // Negotiator expects plain object so we need to transform headers
    const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {};
    request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value));

    // Use negotiator and intl-localematcher to get best locale
    let languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages();

    // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
    const locales: string[] = i18n.locales;
    return matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale);
}

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    // Skip next internal requests
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next")) return;

    // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
    const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
    const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every((locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`);

    // Let's redirect if there is no locale
    if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
        const locale = getLocale(request);
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${locale}/${pathname}`, request.url));
    }
}

export const config = {
    // We can enable redirect just from root
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)"],
};
```

### File tree structure

[Localized App, File tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjFcB.png)

### Error message

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zORA.png)

### Things I tried

- [Route segments configuration options](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/segment-config)  within the page component
- I created a dummy app without localization; I was able to fetch supabase data "without any bugs" [demo app](https://nextjs-supabase-playground.vercel.app)

I trying to fetch supabase data without having the app crashing on me with the error message listed above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to take place within the latest nextjs update > "13.1.6-canary.0".

Solution:
I downgraded from "13-2-1" to "13.1.6-canary.0" as suggested in the following post.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45134#issuecomment-1401196633